# Mysql - Order in group by , select latest from group

Tags: mysql, group-by

See I have a table

```
id  col1 col2
1    a    x
2    b    y
3    c    z
4    a    x
5    b    y
6    c    z
7    a    x
8    b    y
9    c    z
10   a    p
11   b    q
12   c    r
```

To get that you need to do these queries:

```
create database test_db_one;
use test_db_one;
create table test_table_one (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    col1 varchar(3),
    col2 varchar(4),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO test_table_one(col1,col2) VALUES ('a','x'),('b','y'),('c','z'),('a','x'),('b','y'),('c','z'),('a','x'),('b','y'),('c','z'),('a','p'),('b','q'),('c','r');
```

I want following result,

```
id col1 col2
7   a   x
8   b   y
9   c   z
10  a   p
11  b   q
12  c   r
```

I do group by col1,col2 to get the above result

```
select * from test_table_one group by col1,col2;
```

But I get wrong result which is

```
+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
| 10 | a    | p    |
|  1 | a    | x    |
| 11 | b    | q    |
|  2 | b    | y    |
| 12 | c    | r    |
|  3 | c    | z    |
+----+------+------+
```

I don't want id 3,2,1 here, I want ids 9,8,7 instead of them, they should be latest, I hope you got what I meant, the latest ids from the group.
Been struggling with it now, any ideas?

Edit:
I can't do ORDER BY (order by does not give the required result anyways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this can be simply solved with `MAX()` :

```
SELECT MAX(t.id) as max_id,t.col1,t.col2
FROM test_table_one
GROUP BY t.col1,t.col2
ORDER BY max_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
    max(id), col1, col2
from
    test_table_one
group by col1 , col2
order by id;
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f7b5/3)

Comment: Isn't that the same answer as mine ?

Comment: Now it's the exact copy of mine